# Choose maximum from two Excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

We have two pricing models for an item.

- `Price 1` = Cell 1
- `Price 2` = Cell 2

Is there a formula that I can use where the price for the customer would be the whichever is higher among `Price 1` and `Price 2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following:

- Put 27 in Cell B2
- Put 35 in Cell B3
- Put `=MAX(B2:B3)` in B4

When done, B4 better be 35

It also works on rectangular ranges

- Put 27 in Cell B2
- Put 35 in Cell B3
- Put 37 in Cell C2
- Put 31 in Cell C3
- Put `=MAX(B2:C3)` in B4

When done, B4 better be 37

To be honest, both question and answer are trivial.

Using the B4 Cell, when you type =MAX, a little help screen pops up to give you the option to add cells/values.

I am using Excel 2010, BTW

Click on the `File` tab, look to the far right and you will see the Greek Letter Sigma.

Click on the Sigma's DropDown Arrow and Choose More Functions. You will get a list of Functions available in Excel to Insert into the Cell.